# if cookie is set, embed google analytics

Tags: javascript

I want to execute something like this:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('cookie') > -1 ) {
  <script>...
  <script>
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   etc.
}
```

and I read somewhere else that document.write is a bad way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it opposite way. Use `<script>` tag and then `if` inside:

```
<script>
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('cookie') > -1 ) {
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        /* ... */
    }
</script>
```

Then if no cookie present, script simply will not initiate.

---

If you need some custom tag, use this code (in jQuery, but you will get the idea)

```
var head = $('head'); // Select <head>, or any other element that will wrap your script
var scriptTag = $('<script>', {async: 'async', src: 'http://google.com/...', /*... */}); // Create new element in head

head.prepend(scriptTag); // Put your new element to the end of <head>
```

But do you really need that? Try to use [`jQuery.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: That sounds right. What about <script> in that syntax?

Comment: I can see the idea, but I don't know how to embed the <script async src="https://www.gooogle..."> stuff inside that.